# Sum even numbers without using while

Tags: r

I am stuck with a sum that I don't know how to solve this problem. I need to sum even numbers from 2 to 20, and this numbers sum 3.

```r
n<-20
j<-0
for (i in 1:n) {
  if(i %% 2 == 0)
    j<-i+3
print(j)
}
```

```r
Output:
[1] 0  
[1] 5  
[1] 5   
[1] 7  
[1] 7  
[1] 9  
[1] 9  
[1] 11  
[1] 11  
[1] 13  
[1] 13  
[1] 15  
[1] 15  
[1] 17  
[1] 17  
[1] 19  
[1] 19  
[1] 21  
[1] 21  
[1] 23
```

With the function that I used I got the answer, but I don't know why it is repeated twice.

Comment: Rename `j` to be `sum_so_far`. Instead of `j <- i + 3`, use `sum_so_far <- sum_so_far + ***`, where I leave `***` for you to think about and fill in. As a hint, `***` should not be `3`.

Comment: The print is outside the if statement so it prints on every iteration, not just the even ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add curly braces:

```
for (i in 1:n) {
    if(i %% 2 == 0){
        j <- i+3
        print(j)
   }         
}
```

You can get the same outcome without using the loop:

```
vec <- 1:20

vec[vec %% 2 == 0] + 3
```